# Build d3 line chart based on javascript json variable

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Edited: added zooming.

I'm getting data from php function (just sql request) to js variable, so js variable is json data. I need to build zoomable d3 line chart based on this json.
Json variable looks like this:

```
[{temp: "5", created_at: "2017-03-19"},
{temp: "5", created_at: "2017-03-19"},
{temp: "26", created_at: "2018-04-20"}]
```

Error is: `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…"`

```
 Line_chart.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line); ///One error is on this line

    context.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line2); ///Second error is on this line





 var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 430, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%M-%D");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scaleLinear().range([height2, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.Date); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.Air_Temp); });

    var line2 = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x2(d.Date); })
        .y(function (d) { return y2(d.Air_Temp); });

    var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0);


    var Line_chart = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");


    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");




var data = jsonfile

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.created_at; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.temp; })]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());


    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(yAxis);

    Line_chart.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);

    context.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line2);


  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x.range());

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "zoom")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);


  console.log(data);







function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  Line_chart.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  Line_chart.select(".line").attr("d", line);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
}

function type(d) {
  d.Date = parseDate(d.created_at);
  d.Air_Temp = +d.temp;
  return d;
}
```

jsonfile in d3.json is this json variable.

I have problem with dislaying data. I have x and y axis but no displayed data.

---------Reason of the error is incorrectly parsed data, still don't know where code goes wrong.-----------

I added: after `var data = jsonfile`

```
data.forEach(function(d){
  d.created_at = parseDate(d.created_at);
  d.temp = +d.temp;
});
```

And it worked. Graph builds using console. Don't why and where json strings parsed incorrectly.

Comment: So as I understand the chart renders as it should on Google Chrome, but not on Firefox as it there fails to import the json-file? Are you able to recreate the problem in a code sandbox/code pen?

Comment: There are no errors in google chrome console, but it only creates space for d3 graph. I'm trying to rewrite this graph without d3.json, because jsonfile is a json object, and there is no need to load data

Comment: @Jully Could you please reproduce this on jsfiddle or something? So that we can work on it

Comment: Thanks for reply, I added my last corrections in the answer)